# plotting on googlemaps using pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, gmplot

Hi all:) i'm a newbie to python and was given this assignment that i'm finding impossible to figure out. I'm hoping someone here can help me out.
i was given 3 excel files containing info about airpollution levels around europe (i am not able to share these files)
i need to draw on googlemaps the coordinates and airpollution level for specific countries (malta, italy, poland, germany and france). this is the code i'm using:

```
import gmplot #importing of gmplot
import pandas as pd #importing of pandas

df = pd.read_excel (data_path_eu_2016) #i know this is meant to be a path, however i saved the path 
 in a variable earlieer on in my code so im using the variable name here so that the user will only 
need to insert their path once when using my code
df_lat =df['Latitude'] #picking the latitudes
df_lon =df['Longitude'] #picking of the longitude
df_Country = df['Country']  #i'm including these variables as my assignment instructions says to use 
them though im not sure how to incorporate them in this googlemaps plot
df_City = df['City']
df_AirPollutionLevel = df['AirPollutionLevel']
df_Altitude = df['Altitude']

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(48.925278, 2.356667, 5) #chose a random set of coordinates from one of 
the countries i need to plot data for
gmap.scatter(df_lat[:1000], df_lon[:1000], 'red', size = 10) #Scattering of the coordinates using the 
lat and long list
gmap.draw(r"C:\Users\julia\OneDrive\Documents\python assignment\gmplot_Map.html") #the location where 
the HTML file is to be saved
```

however i get this error:
traceback error:  df_lat =df['Latitude'] #picking the latitudes
KeyError: 'Latitude'

the column name 'latitude' exists in my excel files so i'm not sure what the error is about?

i would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Pandas' column names are case-sensistive. In your question you state that the column name is 'latitude', however you wrote 'Latitude' in your script, so most likely the problem is the capitalization.. Try changing this line:

`df_lat =df['Latitude']`

to this:

`df_lat =df['latitude']`

and I'm guesing the same problem will persist for other columns, so make sure you validate that the column names in the script are exactly the same as in the excel file.